# Unable to get the item's position in Spinner using getSelectedItemPosition()

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have to pass the position of item selected in spinner to another activity. I'm using:

```
 int result = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
```

But, this 'result' does not show the correct position selected. Though when I use:

```
        String bloodGroup = String.valueOf(spinner.getSelectedItem());
```

this shows correct result..

what might have been going wrong in the first case?

Comment: what is the value of result after calling int result = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();?

Comment: it is always returning 1

Comment: could you edit your question and give us a little bit more code, maybe the whole event function, it's quite hard to get to the bottom of this with this little information

Comment: it MUST work!! i doubt you are overwriting result value somewhere show us your code.

Comment: the whole code may not be of much help. because i m asking the user to select one of the bloodgroups from the spinner. And that position has to be sent to the next activity for further use. But this position is not coming right! :(

Comment: Yes! my bad! i'm sorry to trouble you both. The value was being overwritten which made the value messed up! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That code should work. Try adding a `onItemSelectedListener()` to the spinner, and log the selected value everytime you change the spinner value. Then you'll see if it's the correct one or not. Most likely you're reseting that value somewhere else.